# Can I use a jsp:include to include an entire JSP page as tab content?

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to define JSP pages as content for my tabs using the "jsp:include" - like this *(Note: "page0.jsp")*...

```
        <ul id="smTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/#page0"    data-toggle="tab">Page0</a>
            </li>   
        -
        -
        -
        <div id="smTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="page0">
                <jsp:include page="page0.jsp" />                     
            </div>
```

**The problem:**

When the user clicks on a tab, the "included"  (i.e., "jsp:include")  JSP page form fields are empty because the controller has not been initialized.

**QUESTION:**

What "href=" value will succeed in both revealing the tab contents (e.g., page0.jsp) and, as well, initialize the controller so the page is displayed properly with data?

Thanks for any help.

**Here's what the *empty* form for page0.jsp looks like...**

[image]

**Here is what it should look like...**

[image]

---

---

***BELOW IS EXTRA INFORMATION IF INTERESTED...***

**Here is the tabbedPage.jsp**

```
    <%@taglib prefix="form"     uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="c"        uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="spring"   uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="fmt"      uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>           

    <br/><br/><br/>

    <div class="page-header"><h1>Tabbed Page Management</h1></div>

    <div class="bs-component">
        <ul id="smTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/#page0"    data-toggle="tab">Page0</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a href="/#page1"    data-toggle="tab">Page1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/#page2"    data-toggle="tab">Page2</a>
            </li>             
        </ul>
        <div id="smTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="page0">
                <h4>${page0FormBean}</h4>
                <jsp:include page="page0.jsp" />                     
            </div>            
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page1">
                <h4>${page1FormBean}</h4>            
                <jsp:include page="page1.jsp" />                     
            </div>            
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page2">
                <h4>${page2FormBean}</h4>              
                <jsp:include page="page2.jsp" />                     
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

**here is the controller for "tabbedPage.jsp"...: TabbedPageController.java**

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    @Controller
    @Scope("session")
    public class TabbedPageController
    {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("TabbedPageController");   

        @RequestMapping(value = {"/tabbedPage"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String tabbedPage(ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
        {
            LOG.info("_________________________tabbedPage_________________________entering...");

            return "tabbedPage";
        }      

    }
```

**Here is page0.jsp (one of the JSP pages included...i.e., via "jsp:include")**

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c"        uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="form"     uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="spring"   uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="fmt"      uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>  

    <br/><br/><br/>
    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h2 class='panel-title'>Page0</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form:form id="page0Form" modelAttribute="page0FormBean" method="post">

        <div class="form-group row-fluid">
            <label class='col-xs-6 control-label' for='formFieldA'>Page0's Form Field A</label>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                <input class='form-control' type='text' id='formFieldA' value='${page0FormBean.formFieldA}' />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row-fluid">
            <label class='col-xs-6 control-label' for='formFieldB'>Page0's Form Field B</label>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                <input class='form-control' type='text' id='formFieldB' value='${page0FormBean.formFieldB}' />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row-fluid">
            <label class='col-xs-6 control-label' for='formFieldC'>Page0's Form Field C</label>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>
                <input class='form-control' type='text' id='formFieldC' value='${page0FormBean.formFieldC}' />
            </div>
        </div>

    </form:form>
```

**here is the controller for "page0.jsp"...: Page0Controller.java**

```
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    @Scope("session")
    public class Page0Controller implements Serializable
    {

        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("Page0Controller");
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1602123387257827883L;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/page0", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView page0(ModelMap model)
        {
            LOG.info("____________________page0___________________entering...");
            Page0FormBean page0FormBean = new Page0FormBean("page0fieldavalue", "page0fieldbvalue", "page0fieldcvalue");
            model.addAttribute("page0FormBean", page0FormBean);

            return new ModelAndView("tabbedPage", "page0FormBean", page0FormBean);
        }
    }
```

**here is the "form bean" used by "page0.jsp"...: Page0FormBean.java**

```
    public class Page0FormBean
    {
        private String formFieldA;
        private String formFieldB;
        private String formFieldC;

        public Page0FormBean(String formFieldA, String formFieldB, String formFieldC)
        {
            this.formFieldA = formFieldA;
            this.formFieldB = formFieldB;
            this.formFieldC = formFieldC;
        }

        public String getFormFieldA()
        {
            return formFieldA;
        }
        public void setFormFieldA(String formFieldA)
        {
            this.formFieldA = formFieldA;
        }

        public String getFormFieldB()
        {
            return formFieldB;
        }
        public void setFormFieldB(String formFieldB)
        {
            this.formFieldB = formFieldB;
        }

        public String getFormFieldC()
        {
            return formFieldC;
        }
        public void setFormFieldC(String formFieldC)
        {
            this.formFieldC = formFieldC;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Page0FormBean{" + "formFieldA=" + formFieldA + ", formFieldB=" + formFieldB + ", formFieldC=" + formFieldC + '}';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've arrived at a solution for now.  - Hopefully, the Spring MVC mavens will chime in if they have a better approach

Essentially, I am using a session scope variable:  "tabno".  -I use "tabno" in the JSP page to control the active tab, etc.  (Note: the use of a ternary expression in EL)

Instead of `href=#page0`, I am instead using `href=page1` to invoke the page0.jsp's controller.
-Page0Controller then passes control to TabbedPageController, and page0.jsp is displayed as "tab content' in tabbedPage.jsp.

Works for now.

Thanks

**The tab JSP code looks like this..**.

```
    -
    -
    -
    <div class="bs-component">
        <ul id="smTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">  <%-- <%pageContext.forward("page1.jsp");%> --%>
            <li class="${sessionScope.tabno==0?'active':''}" >
                <a href="page0">Page0</a>
            </li>   
            <li class="${sessionScope.tabno==1?'active':''}" >
                <a href="page1">Page1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="${sessionScope.tabno==2?'active':''}" >
                <a href="page2">Page2</a>
            </li>             
        </ul>
        <div id="smTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="${sessionScope.tabno==0?'tab-pane fade active in':'tab-pane fade'}" id="page0">
                <jsp:include page="page0.jsp" />                     
            </div>            
            <div class="${sessionScope.tabno==1?'tab-pane fade active in':'tab-pane fade'}" id="page1">         
                <jsp:include page="page1.jsp" />                     
            </div>            
            <div class="${sessionScope.tabno==2?'tab-pane fade active in':'tab-pane fade'}" id="page2">       
                <jsp:include page="page2.jsp" />                     
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
    -
    -
    -
```

**Page0Controller.java (associated with page0.jsp) looks like this...** (you can see where I set the "tabno" value in a session attribute)...

```
    @Controller
    @Scope("session")
    public class Page0Controller implements Serializable
    {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("Page0Controller");
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1602123387257827883L;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/page0", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView page0(ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
        {
            Page0FormBean page0FormBean = new Page0FormBean("page0fieldavalue", "page0fieldbvalue", "page0fieldcvalue");
            model.addAttribute("page0FormBean", page0FormBean);  //<== setting the "modelAttribute" that's used in page.jsp...

            session.setAttribute("tabno", "0");  //<== setting "tabno" value here...

            return new ModelAndView("tabbedPage", "page0FormBean", page0FormBean);
        }
    }
```

**TabbedPageController.java (associated with tabbedPage.jsp) looks like this...**

```
    @Controller
    @Scope("session")
    public class TabbedPageController implements Serializable
    {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("TabbedPageController");   
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6570072463879652843L;

        @RequestMapping(value = {"/tabbedPage"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String tabbedPage(ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
        {
            return "tabbedPage";
        }      
    }
```